# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild' , when tried to run java program in android studio

Tags: java, android

Getting the below error at the time of running java program in android studio.

Error:Execution failed for task ':**app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild**'.

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

Any solution please. ?

Comment: For this you have to take a look at your dependencies and make sure that there are none of these conflicts. If you would like us to help you it will help to post your dependencies.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. This is ridiculous. **It's a fresh new project.** Why would this happen?! Android Studio 3.0.1

Answer (score 22, accepted):

thanks to @Ganesh Bhat and Chad Bingham

For those who still facing the problem, above answer did not help me in android studio 2.2 Preview.

**This fixed my issue.**

add this to your gradle file.

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
 }
}
```

Reference:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/blob/05a57bf43b9b61f16d32cbe8717af77cd608b0fb/build.gradle#L136-L140

[Android support library error after updating to 23.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833606/android-support-library-error-after-updating-to-23-3-0)

[Resolved versions for app (22.0.0) and test app (21.0.3) differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999124/resolved-versions-for-app-22-0-0-and-test-app-21-0-3-differ)

---

update
**- if the previous answer doesn't work :**

you should update the **compileSdkVersion** and **appcompat** to the latest update till now compileSdkVersion is 27 ,
also appcompat is 27.1.1 and  28.0.0-alpha1 is a pre-release version

thus

change

> compileSdkVersion 27

[image: the attached photo will help you]

and

> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

to latest update

> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

you can check the latest updates from this link :

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions

Comment: On pint answer :)

Comment: I also updated  `com.android.support` to 27: `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'` and `targetSdkVersion` to 27.

Comment: perfect Answer, got success in first attempt

Answer (score 27):

Use `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'` 
instead of `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'` and change compileSdkVersion 26 to 27

Comment: I also updated  `com.android.support` to 27: `implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'` and `targetSdkVersion` to 27.

Comment: What if I want to stay with SDK 26? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I answered before some minutes same question [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50088975/6891563). If you are not going to implement testing code, then remove junit from your app.

There are lot of other questions related to this.

[Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (23.3.0) and test app (23.1.1) differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36561037/conflict-with-dependency-com-android-supportsupport-annotations-resolved-ver/36836254)

[Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (23.1.0) and test app (23.0.1) differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317555/conflict-with-dependency-com-android-supportsupport-annotations-resolved-ver/33318482)

Comment: Great !! Thank you.

Comment: You can show your thank by upvote or mark right too :)

Comment: @SrujanBarai you can refer to the related answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your app gradle file

```
configurations.all {
   resolutionStrategy {
      force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines within your **app dependencies** braces,

```
android{
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    }
}
```

Latest is 27.1.1 upto this date.

Answer (score 1):

AS configuration version:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
**androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'**
```

Modify:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
**androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'**
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I too faced the same problem here is how I fixed it

- Goto app level Gradle file

There you will find what are all the config's you have set up. In my case here

```
android{
    **compileSdkVersion 26**
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyyyy.zzz"
        minSdkVersion 19
        **targetSdkVersion 26**
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    **implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'**
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

So here just change the compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion from 26 to 27
and

from dependencies change support appcomat

```
from   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' 
to     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'


android {
    **compileSdkVersion 27**
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxxxxxxx.yyyyyyyy.zzz"
        minSdkVersion 19
        **targetSdkVersion 27**
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    **implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'**
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Got Fixed !!!

Comment: This answer is clear and works to help install Android Studio 3.0.1 for the Android Oreo course on Udemy.

Answer (score 0):

Hello guys I had the same problem for solving this problem u need to change you appcompat in your app bulid gradle to

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

then it should ask you to instal it if u have'nt installed if still errore didnt solved change your sdkversions it will help alot because if u change the appcompact 
to 27.1.1 u need to change your sdkversion to 27 as well i suggest all of u to update your android studio and the sdk to the lastest

Answer (score 0):

Error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
>
> > Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app
> >     (27.1.1) differ. See
> >     https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for
> >     details.

This is due to there is no dependency added to your App build.gradle or might be its an old version. So, add a dependency for annotation support.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
```

Here I have added annotation version 27.1.1 to solve your error if this is mismatched with different version then change it to the required version.

Answer (score 0):

Try below change if it helps you

com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0

to

com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1

Comment: This exception usually thrown at time of appcompat version and compile version is not same try to make both are on same version.

Answer (score 0):

I found this very easy.

**We will use update and use same version for all modules.**

#### 1. Go to project level `build.gradle`, use global variables

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlinVersion = '1.2.61'

    ext.global_minSdkVersion = 16
    ext.global_targetSdkVersion = 28
    ext.global_buildToolsVersion = '28.0.1'
    ext.global_supportLibVersion = '27.1.1'
}
```

#### 2. Go to app level `build.gradle`, and use global variables

**app level `build.gradle`**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion global_targetSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion global_buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion global_minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion global_targetSdkVersion
}
...

dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$global_supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$global_supportLibVersion"
    // and so on...
}
```

**some library/module `build.gradle`**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion global_targetSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion global_buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion global_minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion global_targetSdkVersion
}
...

dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$global_supportLibVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$global_supportLibVersion"
    // and so on...
}
```

*The solution is to make your versions same as in all modules. So that you don't have conflicts.*

#### Tips for future

> I felt when I have updated versions of everything- gradle, sdks,
>   libraries etc. then I face less errors. Because developers are working
>   hard to make it easy development on Android Studio.

**Always have **latest** but stable versions** Unstable versions are `alpha`, `beta` and `rc`, ignore them in developing.

I have updated all below in my projects, and feel flawless coding.

- Update Android Studio (Track [release](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/))
- Project level `build.gradle` - `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'` ([Track `android.build.gradle` release](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google) & [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin))
- Have updated `buildToolVersion` (Track [buildToolVersion release](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools))
- Have latest `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` [Track platform release](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms)
- Have updated library versions, because after above updates, its necessary. (@See [How to update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683327/how-to-check-if-gradle-dependency-has-new-version))

Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

its important to take a look at this too, in your gradle

```
targetSdkVersion 27
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Auto Import Settings]

Go to settings>editor>  Then check those two boxes as displayed in the image. It should solve it without any issue.

Answer (score -1):

Add This Code to the bottom of build.gradle at app level. It will work...

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency{
        DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested=details.requested
            if(requested.group=="com.android.support"){
            if(!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")){
                details.useVersion("26.0.1")
            }
        }
    }
}
```